# What do computers do when usb is detected?

Tags: usb

I was just wondering what computers do when an usb is detected(plugged in). Im assuming theres some sort of scanning but i dont know any of the details :/

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how technical or detailed of an answer your looking for, I'll give a high level overview and some links. They enumerate the device (give it a number or ID on the USB bus), query it's requirements and identification, load device drivers and bring the device online to use. It's a simple process at its core.

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/usb.htm

http://www.geoffknagge.com/uni/elec101/essay.shtml